# Java Unexpected type error

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that will consume two Strings. It will Compare String 1 with String 2 and will replace all unfound chars with '_'. For example if String 1 = "Hello"; String 2 = "eo" then the method will return String 1 as "_e__o" Here is my code:

```
static String getRevealedChars (String s1, String s2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < s2.length(); c++)
        {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(c))
            {
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                // this is where I get my Error
                s1.charAt(i) = '_';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code I get a "unexpected type" error at s1.charAt(i) = '_';. I'm really new to java, thanks in advance.

Comment: `s1.charAt(i) = '_';`  is invalid.

Comment: Key point - `String` objects are immutable.  So you can't change your `String` _in situ_ - you'll have to make a brand new `String` to return.  You might find it easiest to build a `char[]` and convert it to `String` at the end.

Comment: how do I convert a char array to a String?

Comment: `new String(yourCharArray);`

Comment: i tried creating an array but i dont know how to keep adding char values into an array

Answer (score 0):

Replace datatype of `s1` and s2 `from` `String` to `StringBuilder`, then use `setCharAt()` instead of `charAt()` as follows:

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("hello");
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("eo");

static String getRevealedChars (StringBuilder s1, StringBuilder s2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < s2.length(); c++)
        {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(c))
            {
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                // this is where I corrected Error
                s1.setCharAt(i, '_');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.